# ADFS 2.1 Relying Party Trusts

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs2.1

I'm totally baffled about the interface to ADFS 2.1 in Windows Server 2008 R2. I've installed the Active Directory Federation Services with the Claims-aware Agent. However, I cannot figure out how to add a relying party trust, as I can in ADFS 2.0.

When I look at the ADFS management tool, I see only:

```
Active Directory Federation Services
  Federation Service
    Trust Policy
      My Organization
        Organization Claims
        Account Stores
        Applications
      Partner Organizations
        Account Partners
        Resource Partners
```

I don't see the old tree:

```
AD FS 2.0
  Service
    Endpoints
    Certificates
    Claim Descriptions
  Trust Relationships
    Claims Provider Trusts
    Relying Party Trusts
    Attribute Stores
```

I know I'm missing some concept somewhere, but not sure where. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat confused by your question?

ADFS 2.1 only runs on Server 2012.

The word "agent" makes me think that you have loaded ADFS 1.0 which is the default on Server 2008 R2.

ADFS 2.0 is a seperate download.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was confused. ADFS 2.1 installs through a server role, rather than an installation package. When I looked on Windows Server 2008 R2, there is, indeed, a server role for Active Directory Federated Services. Once I installed that, however, I did not see what I expected. I have now installed the ADFS 2.0 package on 2008 R2 and all is good. Thanks for your reply!